# Error during export of large SSRS report via ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, connection-timeout

I have an MVC3 application that delivers SQL Server 2008 reports using the Microsoft ReportViewer web control. Generally everything is working fine, except when exporting large reports to PDF.

At exactly 2 minutes into the export I get the following Server Error:

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out
```

Digging deeper into the error, the SQL Report Server Log is pretty helpful:

```
Error: "RsException: A client has disconnected from Report Server"
Error Code: 800708CA: No connection available
```

So, my guess is that the ReportViewer connection timeout is a config setting somewhere, but I don't know where. We've already looked at all the configuration settings [mentioned here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2009/09/24/troubleshooting-timeout-errors-in-reporting-services.aspx) but nothing is working - the timout always occurs at 2 minutes into the export!

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of SSRS configuration knowledge and neither do the company who actually host the the servers (the client's IT dept). So any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look into the `executionTimeout` setting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx). Default is 110 seconds.

Comment: Hi merekel. That is fantastic cheers. That's fixed it!

Comment: It's good practice to mark answer which was help you as "Best answer" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Submitting this an answer since it worked.

Maybe look into the `executionTimeout` setting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the web.config file. Default is 110 seconds.